# Display HTML File in Express Using Post Request?

Tags: javascript, api, express, post, get

I want to submit my form data and navigate to an HTML file with the data values showing dynamically.

Here is my code in my app.post function for express

```
 const results = fs.readFile("order.html", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    let output = data.replace("{%foodTotal%}", response.data.order_value);
    console.log("output", output);
  });

  res.send(results);
```

So after I submit my input form data, this code will log all my data in the console.

**So my console in my terminal will look like this**

```
output
    <body>
        <h1>Thank you for buying!</h1>
        <p>Here are your details</p>
        <p>Food Total: $100.00</p>
    </body>
```

My problem is I don't know how to get this console.log() data to show up in my browser?

Here is the `order.html` File I am trying to get to display after submitting my form

```
<body>
    <h1>Thank you for buying!</h1>
    <p>Here are your details</p>
    <p>Food Total: {%foodTotal%}</p>
</body>
```

And here is the app.get in my express file

```
app.get("/order", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "order.html"));
});
```

If I try to change my `res.send()` to `res.redirect('order')` it will only show my HTML normally, but won't include the updated values from my form when I submit it

**My Goal is the be able to submit my form and have it showcase my HTML file `order.html` with the data like this in my browser and not my terminal**

```
<body>
    <h1>Thank you for buying!</h1>
    <p>Here are your details</p>
    <p>Food Total: $100.00</p>
</body>
```

Is this possible with regular html files? Or would I need to use something like EJS?

My previous solution was the hardcode the HTML in my express.js file, but that doesn't seem proper

Comment: You should use some sort of template engine like EJS. Besides that, your code is wrong. `fs.readFile()` returns `undefined` so results with always be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you will need some form of templating.

[The accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72558018/how-to-find-exact-matched-pattern-in-a-text/72558220#72558220) details a hand-rolled templating engine which would be suitable for simple a usecase such as you describe.

As your app becomes more complicated, you might consider [adopting a templating engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: what would happen to my project if I already use a main index.html file for getting my form data and I only need the `order.html` file to be used as a template? Am I able to mix regular html files with EJS in my project?

Comment: which one is preferred for a simple html file? Pug or EJS? I never used any before so I don't know the difference

Comment: I'm not sure there would be a "preferred" option. It's really up to you. Try to imagine the smallest change you can make and take it from there.

Comment: So I added pug but I don't see the difference in how I would render my file? Wouldn't I just replace my order.html with order.pug?

Comment: Try something like `res.render('order', { order_value: 100 })`. If you get stuck, take a look at the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). The rest, is up to you.